# Read binary files and separate the 64-bit unsigned integers into certain forms？

Tags: list-manipulation, binary

I have a binary file where each data is a 64-bit unsigned integer (**[little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)**). For simplicity, let's say the data in `testdata.bin` file opened in [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is:

[image]
namely:

> CA 35 58 C8 8C 00 01 00
> 87 88 6A C8 8C 00 02 00
> 5F B2 83 C9 8C 00 03 00
> CB 5F 86 C9 8C 00 01 00

I want to read the bin file and separate each 64-bit data into two parts (48-bit for one, 16-bit for another). As an example, the data in the first row `CA 35 58 C8 8C 00 01 00` will be separated to `CA 35 58 C8 8C 00` and `01 00`(**notice that they are in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)**), and then read in **decimal format** as `{604656645578, 1}`. In this case, `CA 35 58 C8 8C 00`stands for `604656645578` and `01 00` is for `1`.

For testing, one can create `testdata.bin` with the following codes:

```
hexnumber = {{"CA", "35", "58", "C8", "8C", "00", "01", "00"}, {"87", 
    "88", "6A", "C8", "8C", "00", "02", "00"}, {"5F", "B2", "83", 
    "C9", "8C", "00", "03", "00"}, {"CB", "5F", "86", "C9", "8C", 
    "00", "01", "00"}};
bincreate = {};
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[hexnumber], ii++,
  For[kk = 1, kk <= 8, kk++,
    AppendTo[bincreate, 
      Interpreter["HexInteger"][hexnumber[[ii]][[kk]]]];
    ];
  ];

binname = "testdata.bin";
currentdirectory = NotebookDirectory[];
pSite = FileNameJoin[{currentdirectory, binname}];
If[FileExistsQ[binname] == False, binfile = CreateFile[pSite], 
 binfile = pSite;]
BinaryWrite[binfile, bincreate];
```

**Q:** I want to read the bin file and the results somehow in the following form:

> {{604656645578, 1}, {604657846407, 2}, {604676272735, 3}, {604676448203, 1}}

i.e. `604656645578` is given by `CA 35 58 C8 8C 00` in little endian.

I thought it might work by using `BinaryReadList` with `Integer8` and recombine them for 48-bit and 16-bit, but not sure. Is it possible to do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
endianFlip[b_] := FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[b, 256]], 256]

{endianFlip[BitShiftRight[#, 16]], endianFlip[BitAnd[#, 2^16 - 1]]} & /@ 
 BinaryReadList["test.bin", "UnsignedInteger64", ByteOrdering -> 1]
```

This first reads in the whole file in big-endian unsigned 64-bit integers. For each entry it shifts down by two bytes for the first 48-bit item, and masks off the top 6 bytes with the bitwise AND to give the two bytes for the second item. Finally, both items are flipped back into little-endian.

... and it produces the result you want from your .bin file:

```
(* {{604656645578, 1}, {604657846407, 2}, {604676272735, 3}, {604676448203, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot! @flinty